# Spring Security Login Failure

Tags: spring, security, jsf, authentication

I am using Spring Security 3.0.6 with JSF Mojarra 2.1.18 and Primefaces 3.5.

I created a LoginManagedBean which injects the AuthenticationManager of Spring Security.

```
 @ManagedBean
    @SessionScoped
    public class LoginManagedBean implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private static transient final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(LoginManagedBean.class);

        private LoginDTO login;

        private String username;

        private String password;

        @ManagedProperty(value = "#{authenticationManager}")
        private transient AuthenticationManager authenticationManager = null;

...
```

It works. But if login fails, I can never login again with correct values. I think I need to clear/reset the authenticationManager object but I dont know how. Any Suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You should be it another way.

1) define auth manager

```
<s:authentication-manager>
    <s:authentication-provider>
        <s:user-service>
            <s:user name="root" password="root"/>
        </s:user-service>
    </s:authentication-provider>
</s:authentication-manager>
```

2) define security config and form login

```
<s:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <s:intercept-url pattern="/favicon.ico" access="permitAll"/>
    <s:intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll"/>
    <s:intercept-url pattern="/login**" access="isAnonymous"/>
    <s:intercept-url pattern="/pages/*" access="hasAuthority('ROLE_USER')"/>      
    <s:form-login login-page="/login.xhtml" default-target-url="/"
                  authentication-failure-url="/login.xhtml?loginFailed=true"/>
</s:http>
```

3) put `@EnableWebMvc` on some `@Configuration`

4) create form at `login.xml`to post data (fields `j_username` and `j_password`) to `/j_spring_security_check`

5) add filter to `web.xml`

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: It was a bug in spring security 3.0.6. For some reason the password was erased after BadCredentialsException (see AuthenticationException.java:58). After a failed login the provided password was always check against null, which failed. I switched to 3.0.8 and that solved the problem. I also tried switching to 3.1.3 but this seemed a major task.

Comment: But why are you using authenticationManager directly instead of built in solutions?

Comment: I wanted to do it the JSF way and it seemed easier to me to inject the authenticationManager instead of posting some fields to an URL. By the way I didnt test it but the problem remains the same with 3.0.6. Regards

Comment: I tried doing the way you suggested and like I supposed I had the same behavior as with injected authenticationManager. At least this is true for my project. Another point using a session scoped managed bean instead of built in solution: All managed beans in my app getting the user information from login managed bean (e.g. username, roles) ...

Comment: If you are using my code you may get user info from SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()

Comment: You are right. Maybe it is just a matter of taste using jsf style or jsp style. Best Regards.